# npm showing warning - deprecated core-js@2.6.11

Tags: node.js, npm, pdfkit

> Please note that I know that there are many questions regarding above
>   and they all already answered. I also tried the mentioned solutions to
>   resolve the problem but nothing works for me.

I am using node 13.11.0 binaries on ubuntu.`node version = 13.11.0  npm version = 6.13.7`

I created an new project. I want to install `pdfkit` package.

when i run 
`npm install pdfkit --save`


There is an warning 
`npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.`


I am not using `core-js`.
Why this warning appears?

From which location `npm` fetching the `core-js`?


**What I did to resolve the problem**-

1. cleared **npm cache**.

   2. Installed `core-js = 3.6.4` in the same project.
   3. Installed `core-js = 3.6.4` globally.

But nothing worked. The problem is still here.

How I can resolve the above warning?

How to update the `core-js` to latest version?

#### Is npm using an internal version of `core-js`?

Comment: pdfkit -> fontkit -> babel-runtime -> core-js

Comment: @aloMalbarez Thanks for reply, Ok, so, how I can update the version of `core-js` within `babel-runtime`?